# Android: Add same functionality in different subclasses of Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, inheritance, extends, overriding

I've been questioning myself a long time how to solve this issue but didn't find a proper solution. I have the following subclasses of Fragment:

```
BaseListFragment extends ListFragment
BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
BaseFragment extends Fragment
```

Each of these BaseFragments override the same methods and implement the same functionality. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment
{
    private BaseActivity baseActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
       super.onAttach(context);
       baseActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
       baseActivity = null;
       super.onDetach();
    }

    // other overridden methods.
}

public abstract class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private BaseActivity baseActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
       super.onAttach(context);
       baseActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
       baseActivity = null;
       super.onDetach();
    }

    // other overridden methods.
}

public abstract class BaseListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    private BaseActivity baseActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
       super.onAttach(context);
       baseActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
       baseActivity = null;
       super.onDetach();
    }

    // other overridden methods.
}
```

All other fragments in my app then extend any of these Fragments. However, the problem is that I don't want to code everything three times.

Want can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no other way to solve this unless you create your own custom fragment where you can extend it to your class but that would be messy.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: A custom fragment isn't an option because I need the functionality that ListFragment and DialogFragment provides.

Comment: use [Delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) `class MyFragmentDelegate { private BaseActivity baseActivity; onAttach(context) { baseActivity = (BaseActivity) context; } BaseActivity getBaseActivity() { return ...} /* and so on ....*/}` ... then unfortunately you have to use it in all needed lifecycle methods ... but at least you can maintain the code at one place ... [it is used in support library](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.java)

Comment: @Selvin: Not sure if this works because the delegates in the examples are abstract. My three classes also have some variables that I need to work with. Perhaps you can provide me with a better example on how to call the delegate in this case? Would you be so kind to post an answer so I can accept it if it works?